# how do I sort response fetched from AJAX request and map them as <option> to <select> tag?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to sort the response fetched from backend, using AJAX. This is my code:

```
let $select = $("#colony_code");
  
$.ajax({
      url: 'backend.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { "input": "fetch_colony_codes" }, 
      dataType: 'json', 
      success: function(response) {
        let selectedValue = $select.val();
        let html = response.filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) === i).map(item => `<option value="${item}">${item}</option>`);
        $select.html(html).val(selectedValue);
      },
      complete: function() {}
});
```

Now, I want all the `options` to be sorted in my `<select>` tag. How do I sort the options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, I am stupid. Just adding `response.sort();` in the beginning of the `success(..)` solved my problem. XD

Comment: You should consider accepting this so others can see that your problem was solved, especially if you solved it yourself :)